# I am trying to add a phtml through xml. But I can not add. Code shared below

Tags: magento2, layout, template, xml

trying to add a phtml through xml to account page sidebar. but i am not getting it right.
the xml code is: 
[image]

Comment: Please update your XML content in question

Comment: I was unable to upload xml. so I uploaded a picture.

Comment: You can not upload file but you can copy content of file and then you can paste here

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml" before="-"/>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: the issue is your starting tag is `<referenceContainer>` but your ending tag in `<referenceBlock>`... kindly change `<referenceBlock>` to `<referenceContainer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your `customer_account.xml` file here in this path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sidebar.main.new.template" template="Magento_Customer::customer/sidebar.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And you can create your template file here..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/customer/sidebar.phtml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?php echo "Test content"; ?>
```

After adding both files please run below commands in CLI

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Did you tried this ?

Comment: thank you. but it is not working.

Comment: Where you are trying to add xml file ?

Comment: Can you please send me path of your xml and template file ?

Comment: Magento_Theme/templates/html/test.phtml

Comment: And you've added same content in your xml file which I've added in answer ?

Comment: I think you've added template file here, Am I right ?

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/test.phtml**

Comment: Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

Comment: Wait I'll update my answer and then you can check

Comment: you are right, Sir

Comment: Sure, Sir. I am here

Comment: I've updated my answer, Please review

Comment: You are great! It's working.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Happy to help you! :)